# Using GPS library in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, gps, gpsd

I want to use GPS library in Python 3. I came across this on https://github.com/tpoche/gps-python3

How do I 'install' these files? Should I simple copy them to my folder? Or is there any way of installing them?

Answer (score 3):

That project is a warts and all port of the python-gps package to Python 3.

The python-gps files live at `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gps/`

You can put **gps-python3** files in your Python 3 path by creating and placing them in an analogous directory, e.g., `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gps/`   The module will then be available as it would in Python2.  There is no *installer*

Another option is use [gps3.py](https://github.com/wadda/gps3).  It's still alpha, but is a fresh python client for the gpsd.  It works with any Python from 2.7 to 3.4.  It can be either placed in a directory such as `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/gps/`, placed in the directory of your python script, or executed directly via `python3 /path/to/gps3.py`

Your python script is easy to adapt as it uses the same name(s) as the json stream from the gpsd.

```
from gps3 import gps3
the_connection = gps3.GPSDSocket() 
the_fix = gps3.Fix()
try:
    for new_data in the_connection:
        if new_data:
            the_fix.refresh(new_data)
        if not isinstance(the_fix.TPV['lat'], str): # lat as determinate of when data is 'valid'
            speed = the_fix.TPV['speed']
            latitude = the_fix.TPV['lat']
            longitude = the_fix.TPV['lon']
            altitude  = the_fix.TPV['alt']
            # etc....
```

Comment: I try to place them at the directory /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages but I get an error saying 
gps: Error creating directory: Permission denied

I'm doing this on Raspberry Pi. Is there anyway to get around this?

Comment: `sudo mkdir  /usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/gps/` and then `sudo cp` whatever to whatever

Comment: Could you please revisit this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77998670/python-gpsd-client